# Separated integers with comma delimiters and sscanf

Tags: c, csv, scanf

I need help with sscanf. 
I have a data file. I read it line by line.
One line is look like this: 23,13,45;

I want to read the integers.
I try this code:

```
unsigned char a,b,c;
sscanf(line,"%d,%d,%d;",&a,&b,&c);
```

But this is not working, only the first number read, the others is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `%d` expects a pointer to a 4-byte integer, and you are passing a pointer to a 1-byte `char`. Because variables `a`, `b` and `c` are stored in the order of decreasing memory addresses, `sscanf` first fills `a` with 23, at the same time filling 3 other bytes of stack memory with zeros (this is a memory violation, BTW). Then it fills `b` with 13, also filling `a` and two other bytes with zeros. In the end it fills `c` with 45, also filling `a` and `b` and one other byte with zeros. This way you end up with zeros in both `b` and `a`, and an expected value only in `c`.

Of course this is only one possible scenario of what can happen, as it depends on the architecture and compiler.

A proper way to read 4 integers would be to use `int` instead of `unsigned char`, or change the format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

Correct format specifier for `unsigned char` is `%hhu`.

Other than that I don't see any problem as long as `line` does contain the string in the format you expect.

Comment: For `%d` sscanf() expects a `signed int*` but you are passing pointers to `unsigned char`, which is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).